# why the browser is reloding when i dispatch an add action?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

In the container I have this. In the ngOnit I get all pizzas then  xhen clicking onCreate() Function . the pizza is addedd synch an the browser is reloading

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.pizza$ = this.store.select<any>(fromStore.getAllPizzas);

  this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadPizzas());
}

onCreate(event: Pizza) {
   this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.CreatePizza(event));
}
```

this.is the action file : there ist the diferents actions related to trhe model

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Pizza } from '../../../shared/models/pizza.model';

 export const LOAD_PIZZAS = 'LOAD_PIZZAS';
 export const LOAD_PIZZAS_FAIL = 'LOAD_PIZZAS_FAIL';
 export const LOAD_PIZZAS_SUCCESS = 'LOAD_PIZZAS_SUCCESS';


 export class LoadPizzas implements Action {
   readonly type = LOAD_PIZZAS;
   constructor() { }

 }

  export class LoadPizzasFail implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_PIZZAS_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) { }
   }

   export class LoadPizzasSuccess implements Action {
   readonly type = LOAD_PIZZAS_SUCCESS;
   constructor(public payload: Pizza[]) { }
  }
  // create pizza
  export const CREATE_PIZZA = '[Products] Create Pizza';
  export const CREATE_PIZZA_FAIL = '[Products] Create Pizza Fail';
  export const CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS = '[Products] Create Pizza Success';

  export class CreatePizza implements Action {
    readonly type = CREATE_PIZZA;
    constructor(public payload: Pizza) {}
  }

   export class CreatePizzaFail implements Action {
     readonly type = CREATE_PIZZA_FAIL;
      constructor(public payload: any) {}
   }

    export class CreatePizzaSuccess implements Action {
       readonly type = CREATE_PIZZA_SUCCESS;
        constructor(public payload: Pizza) {}
    }

     export type PizzasAction =
       LoadPizzas |
       LoadPizzasFail |
       LoadPizzasSuccess |
        CreatePizza |
       CreatePizzaFail |
       CreatePizzaSuccess;
```

and this is the container HTML

```
 <app-pizza-create (createPizzaEvent)="onCreate($event)">
 </app-pizza-create>
 <app-pizza-list [pizza$]="pizza$">
 </app-pizza-list>
```

Comment: You say you're clicking for the `onCreate` function, is this button part of a form? If so, make sure to add `type="button"`, otherwise by default it will try to submit the form

Comment: the same think . this is an stanblitz projet . it can be more helpful https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uljpky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpizzas%2Fcontainer%2Fpizza-container.component.ts

Comment: im running also a json web server which provide api via jsonFile     "json-server": "^0.14.0",

Comment: When I click the add button on that stackblitz, nothing happens, however the pizza service is pointing at `localhost:3000`, and I don't have your backend running...

Comment: you must run a json server . this is the git url https://gitlab.com/houssem-amara/ngrx-crud-pizza ; run npm install puis npm run json:server to launch the serer and npm start . and you must change the id evrey time when adding new pizzaa to evit duplication error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your the Angular CLI live reloads the page when one of your files is modified. Because you're appending a record to `db.json`, this will also cause a reload.

To fix this move the file to outside the `src` directory, or disable live reloading completely (I don't know if you can ignore files).

Comment: thanks :D . It did not occur to me . I think that reloading is caused only by 'CL + S '.